# Start rotation on bt. Click and control it with the mouse position

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to start rotation on button click and then be able to control the rotation  angle on mouse position.

Right now my code run the rotation, but i don't know how to start it on a button click and then, control it on mouse position.

I am new to javascript and p5js. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: The line `angle = radians( mouseY / height  * 2.0 * Math.PI * turns );' contains a variable `turns` which is not initialized . Add a line `const turns = 5;` above it. I've corrected my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html button should not be of "type" submit as you are not in a form scope. (A submit button starts the form action.)

The following code is IMHO correct:

```
<html> 
  <input 
     id="BgCategory1-btn1" onclick="a()" 
     class="btn´btn-primary" type="button">
    Background1
  </input>
</html>
```

In `a()` you set a flag `show_grid' which activates the rotation. As you said, this works. But the rotation is derived from the actual time in milli seconds. You only need to use the mouse coordinates to derive the angle from.

The mouse coordinates can be obtained from the variables `mouseX` and `mouseY`.

So, if you want the grid to rotate if you move the mouse to the left or right use:

```
const turns = 5;
let angle = radians( mouseX / width * 2.0 * Math.PI * turns  );
```

And, if you want the grid to rotate if you move the mouse up or down use:

```
const turns = 5;
let angle = radians( mouseY / height  * 2.0 * Math.PI * turns );
```

`hight` and `with` contain the height and with of your canvas (the drawing area) and should be built in variables which can be used in the `draw()` method (like the variables `mouseX` and `mouseY`).

If you want to have a zero degree rotation if the mouse is in the middle of the screen. You have to substract the half screen size from the mouse coordinate.

Just one example, it works for up down likewise:

```
const turns = 5;
let angle = radians( ( mouseX - width / 2 ) / width * 2.0 * Math.PI * turns  );
```

**EDIT:**

As I see now you want to start the rotation by clicking on the picture grid:

You can write a function named `mouseClicked()` and add code to it to set a flag that allows rotation. First initialize a flag variable above the method `draw()`. `let rotAllowed = false;`

```
function mouseClicked() 
{
  rotAllowed = true;
}
```

Check this flag in tn the `draw()` method :

```
push();
let angle = 0;

if ( rotAllowed) 
{
  const turns = 5;
  angle = radians( mouseY / height  * 2.0 * Math.PI * turns );
}

translate( width / 2, height / 2 );
rotate( angle );
translate( -width / 2, -height / 2 );
imageMode( CENTER );
rectMode( CENTER );
layerOne.grid.display();
pop();
```

**Edit2:**

If you need an aditioanl button do the same as with the first button.

```
<html> 
  <input 
     id="BgCategory1-btn1" onclick="a()" 
     class="btn´btn-primary" type="button">
    Background1
  </input>
  <input 
     id="BgCategory1-btn2" onclick="b()" 
     class="btn´btn-primary" type="button">
    Rotation
  </input>
</html>
```

An let it execute function `b()` as the onclick handler.

```
function b()
{
  rotAllowed = true;
}
```

Comment: Thx for answer... But how i can start rotation on bt click?

Comment: What do you mean with "start". The button rotates automatically or the button rotates according to the mouse position? If you remove the `type="submit"` from the html code the onclick handler should work. The `a()` method starts the rotation by setting the flag `show_grid'` and you are ablke to use the mouse to control the rotation angle. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Ah... the line `let show_grid = false;` is misplaced. It must be moved above the first usage of the variable `show_grid`.  At least above the `draw()` method.

Comment: The function a() show grid of images show_grid = true; i want to add rotation to the grid on bt click and control it by the mouse. The mouse controll is solved but how to add rotation on bt click to to the grid? On the begining the grid should not have rotation and after bt click i can rotate it .

Comment: You mean you want to use an additional button to start rotation? The button you already have is for showing the picture grid? But if you want to use the existent button for both (show grid and start rotation by mouse) then, that's what you already have. There is a problem with the variable `show_grid` which is initialize blow its usage in draw. So the draw method uses a global one which is (IMHO') always false.  If you place the line `let show_grid = false;` above the draw method the variable should work as expected.

Comment: Sorry you wrote what you want in the the comment above. But I've misunderstood it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yes aditional bt to start rotation

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete new code. I just don't know what you've really done so far.

Comment: But how can I see what went wrong if you do not show me the code that fails. Pleas add the code the fails. You should not  overwrite your old question, just wite **Edit:* and below insert a short explanation that will add new new code and that i does not work (and why you think it does not work.) and then the code that fails. So others can see what you have so far and perhaps someone else has better ideas than me. In any way if I can not see the failing code, I can not say what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm at work and I won't continue this discussion any further. If this sounds angry; I'm not angry (really), but I have not so much time! If you'll show me your code, I possibly find the problem or perhaps someone other sees it.